# Define structure of flags

Tags: c#

I would like to define structure which will contain eight flags. Is it possible to use byte type instead of 8 boolean fields in it? I would like to have something like this

```
struct mystruct
{
  byte first:1;
  byte second:1;
  ...
}
```

I want binary representation to give me flags value.

And what if I have some values which should take more than 1 bit, e. g. 2 or 4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum Flags Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute)

Comment: I know it's not quite a duplicate, but the `[Flags]` attribute does sound like exactly what you're after here.

Comment: Like a `BitArray` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi undercover It will be converted to bytes look to this:

```
    [FlagsAttribute]
    public enum mystruct: byte
    {
        first= 1,
        second =2
    }
```

Shall I also post for you the IL code?

more info :
[What does the [Flags] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute)

By the way Flags is simply shorthand for FlagsAttribute.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it not with a struct but with an enum, like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFlags
{
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 4,
    Fourth = 8
}
```